# Error in BizTalk server 2010 administation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to poll data from SQL server and receive data in a receive message who have the schema from the table in SQL, then I use a loop to each row by row and transfer each row to file.

In administrator I found an error, the error is:

> The Messaging engine failed to process a message submitted by adapter:WCF-SQL Source URL:mssql://win-f7kl176gt9v//user?InboundId=id2. Details:The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

Answer (score 3):

Run a query to look at your active subscriptions and identify your receive port:
[image: Active Subscriptions]

Then check against your messages promoted properties.  The usual case is that your receive port has the wrong filter i.e. message type etc.

[image: Subscription Detail]

Comment: on suspend service instance i found an routing failure error on receive port which receive port is configure as wcf-sql that receive data from sql

Comment: OK, do the promoted properties of the message meet that of the filter on receive port? Are you using the correct message type?

Comment: yes the receive message have the schema generated by the stored procedure that poll data from sql server,

Comment: Then we need more detail.  Revise your question, add some diagrams, let's see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: give me your gmail and i will send you the documentation

Comment: LOL I don't have time to read documentation, revise your question.

Comment: I want to transfer data from sql-server to file using orchestration that contain receive message and transform and send message,for receive data from sql server i create a stored procedure and i use adapter metadata to generate the schema for receive message,in administration i'm using wcf-sql for receive port and file for send port,but there are a routing failure error in receive port and data will not arrive to receive msg and start orchestration,thanks for help

Comment: Then you must have the wrong filter/message type on your receive port.  Otherwise you would get an error in the orchestration. Check the message you are trying to recieve validates against the schema(message type) you are using.

Comment: he must be valid because the schema is generated by adapter metadata when i select the stored procedure